# Does a father's rebuke cause seven days of humiliation in his child?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, children-parenting, middos-character-traits, behaalotcha-parsha

In [Bamidbor 12:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9940#showrashi=true), Rashi explains the verse to mean that if Miriam's father had turned to her with an angry face, she would have been humiliated for seven days.

Are there other examples where we find that the attitude of a father can cause so long a humiliation in his child?